# AngularJS show 2 models in one controller

Tags: angularjs, express, angularjs-service, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have 2 models(Project and Task) to show in my home.html, and I want my them to be displayed like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ItNvBNBIrLxqwRrhye5p, where both scope of data is shown and filtered based on the same color.

I use an Angular controller (projectCtrl.js) to control data on my web page(home.html), and use an Angular service (projectService.js) to grab data from my api file (api.js) written with express framework and mongoose.

But my code doesn't show anything, so I have no idea what's wrong.

home.html:

```
<div class="row" ng-if="main.loggedIn">
  <div ng-controller="ProjectController">
    <div class="panel col-md-8">
      <!-- Project heading setup -->
      <div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="eachProject in project.projects | reverse track by $index">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="true" data-target="#projectDetails{{$index}}" href="#projectDetails{{$index}}">
            <h4>{{eachProject.title}}: {{eachProject.short_description}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse out" id="projectDetails{{$index}}">
            <p class="panel-body">
              <!-- Project detail table, where project data displays-->
              <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr>
                  <th>Description: </th>
                  <td>{{eachProject.description}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!-- Task heading setup -->
              <div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="eachTask in task.tasks | filter: { projectID: eachProject.id }">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                  <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="true" data-target="#taskDetails{{$index}}" href="#taskDetails{{$index}}">
                    <h5>{{eachTask.title}}</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-collapse collapse out" id="taskDetails{{$index}}">
                    <p class="panel-body">
                      <!-- Task detail table, where tasks data displays -->
                      <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Description: </th>
                          <td>{{eachTask.description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

ProjectCtrl.js

```
angular.module('projectCtrl', ['projectService'])

.controller('ProjectController', function(Project, Task, socketio) {
  var vm = this;
  Project.all()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.projects = data;
  })

  vm.createProject = function() {
    // Wrong due date prevention
    var start = new Date(vm.projectData.start_date);
    var due = new Date(vm.projectData.due_date);
    if (start > due) {
      alert("Due date can't be earlier than start date, please decide a new due date.");
      return;
    }
    // Create project
    vm.message = '';
    Project.create(vm.projectData)
    .success(function(data) {
      // Clear up the project
      vm.projectData = '';
      vm.message = data.message;
      $('#createProject').modal('hide');
    })
  }

  Task.all()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.tasks = data;
  })

  vm.createTask = function() {
    // Wrong due date prevention
    var start = new Date(vm.taskData.taskStart_date);
    var due = new Date(vm.taskData.taskDue_date);
    if (start > due) {
      alert("Due date can't be earlier than start date, please decide a new due date.");
      return;
    }
    // Create task
    vm.message = '';
    Task.create(vm.taskData)
    .success(function(data) {
      // Clear up the task
      vm.taskData = '';
      vm.message = data.message;
      $('#createTask').modal('hide');
    })
  }

  socketio.on('project', 'task', function(data) {
    vm.projects.push(data);
    vm.tasks.push(data);
  })

})

.controller('AllProjectsController', function(projects, socketio) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.projects = projects.data;

  socketio.on('project', function(data) {
    vm.projects.push(data);
  })
})
```

projectService.js

```
angular.module('projectService', [])

.factory('Project', function($http) {
  var projectFactory = {};
  projectFactory.create = function(projectData) {
    return $http.post('/api', projectData);
  }
  projectFactory.allProjects = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/all_projects');
  }
  projectFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/api');
  }
  projectFactory.deleteProject = function(id) {
    return $http.post('/api/deleteProject', {id: id});
  }
  return projectFactory;
})

.factory('Task', function($http) {
  var taskFactory = {};
  taskFactory.create = function(taskData) {
    return $http.post('/api', taskData);
  }
  taskFactory.allTasks = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/all_tasks');
  }
  taskFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/api');
  }
  taskFactory.deleteTask = function(id) {
    return $http.post('/api/deleteTask', {projectID: id});
  }
  return taskFactory;
})

.factory('socketio', function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
          socket.on(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            })
          })
    },

    emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.apply(function() {
          if(callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

api.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var Project = require('../models/project');
var config = require('../../config');
var secretKey = config.secretKey;
var jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fields = '...'; // a lot of fields, deleted them just to make it short

// Create tokens for users with jsonwebtoken
function createToken(user) {
  var token = jsonwebtoken.sign({
    id: user._id,
    firstname: user.firstname,
    lastname: user.lastname,
    username: user.username
  }, secretKey, {
    expirtesInMinute: 1440
  });
  return token;
}

module.exports = function(app, express, io) {
  var api = express.Router();

  api.get('/all_projects', function(req, res) {
    Project.find({}, function(err, projects) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      res.json(projects);
    })
  })

  // login api
  api.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
      username: req.body.username
    }).select(fields).exec(function(err, user) {
      if(err) {
        throw err;
      }
      if (!user) {
        res.send({ message: "User doesn't exist"});
      } else if(user){
        var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
        if (!validPassword) {
          res.send({ message: "Invalid Password"});
        } else {
          var token = createToken(user);
          res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Login Successfully !",
            token: token
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });

  //middleware
  api.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Somebody just logged in!");
    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
      jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secretKey, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(403).send({success: false, message: "Failed to authenticate user."});
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "No Token Provided." });
    }
  });

  //api for projects handling
  api.route('/')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var project = new Project({
      creatorID: req.decoded.id,
      creator: req.decoded.firstname + " " + req.decoded.lastname,
      creator_dept: req.decoded.department,
      title: req.body.title,
      short_description: req.body.short_description,
      description: req.body.description,
      priority: req.body.priority,
      status: calcStatus(),
      assign_dept: req.body.assign_dept,
      estimate_cost: req.body.estimate_cost,
      actual_cost: req.body.actual_cost,
      last_modified_date: req.body.last_modified_date,
      due_date: req.body.due_date,
      start_date: req.body.start_date,
      complete_date: req.body.complete_date,
    });
    project.save(function(err, newProject) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      io.emit('project', newProject);
      res.json({
        message: "New Project Created!"
      });
    });
  })
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Project.find( {creatorID: req.decoded.id}, function(err, project) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      res.json(project);
    });
  });

  //api for tasks handling
  api.route('/')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var task = new Task({
      creatorID: req.decoded.id,
      creator: req.decoded.firstname + " " + req.decoded.lastname,
      projectID: req.body.taskProjectID,
      title: req.body.taskTitle,
      description: req.body.taskDescription,
      status: calcStatus(),
      assigneeName: req.body.assigneeName,
      assigneeID: req.body.assigneeID,
      assignee_dept: req.body.assignee_dept,
      estimate_cost: req.body.taskEstimate_cost,
      actual_cost: req.body.TaskActual_cost,
      last_modified_date: req.body.taskLast_modified_date,
      due_date: req.body.taskDue_date,
      start_date: req.body.taskStart_date,
      complete_date: req.body.taskComplete_date,
    });
    task.save(function(err, newTask) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      io.emit('tasks', newTask);
      res.json({
        message: "New Task Created!"
      });
    });
  })
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Task.find( {projectID: req.decoded.id}, function(err, task) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      res.json(task);
    });
  });
  // api for angular
  api.get('/me', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.decoded);
  });
  return api;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are any errors printed in the console? Have you tried setting breakpoints/tracing the code paths to see where it might be breaking down?

Comment: There is no error in console. And yes I should try setting breakpoints. But can you see anything wrong directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference project.projects here:

`<div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="eachProject in project.projects | reverse track by $index">`

But `project` is never in ProjectController... I think you may want to set `project` to refer to your `ProjectController`, try this:

`<div ng-controller="ProjectController as project">`

**EDIT**

A few other problems. You mentioned you wanted to show all Tasks as well, in ProjectController you populate projects and tasks like so:

```
Project.all()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.projects = data;
  })
....
Task.all()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.tasks = data;
  })
```

That's good, except the definitions for Project.all and Task.all are referencing the same data source:

```
  projectFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/api');
  }

  taskFactory.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/api');
  }
```

They both reference /api. How can they both expect different data from the same route? They should likely be two distinct routes.

In addition, your definition in api.js for this end point requires an ID to be passed to get a single project:

```
.get(function(req, res) {
    Task.find( {projectID: req.decoded.id}, function(err, task) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      res.json(task);
    });
  });

 .get(function(req, res) {
    // The request must contain a creatorId, otherwise you're not going to find your project
    Project.find( {creatorID: req.decoded.id}, function(err, project) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }
      res.json(project);
    });
  });
```

Perhaps your projectService should be pointing to the `/all_projects` end point instead for .all. So to sum up:

1. API end points for Project/Task should be different
2. Be sure to pass the project ID/task if necessary, otherwise you're not going to get the data you're expecting.
3. Set breakpoints and log output to trace your code path to see where other mistakes may be.

Comment: That would only show my projects, but it won't show tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried your advice and now I can find the corresponding task from api, and let it pass through service and controller. But it still doesn't display on home.html. If I only put   <div ng-controller="ProjectController">, it doesn't show anything. But if I put   <div ng-controller="ProjectController as project, task">, it gets me this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlfmt?p0=ProjectController%20as%20project,%20task. So what should I do?

Comment: That's incorrect syntax, it should just be `<div ng-controller="ProjectController as project">`. You can only give the one name to the controller, as there's only one instance.

It seems like your current ProjectController is more like a ProjectListController, since it controls the list of projects... you likely need another controller for a single Project, ie. put a controller on ng-repeat:
`<div class="panel-group" ng-repeat="eachProject in project.projects | reverse track by $index" ng-controller="SingleProjectController">`

Something like that.

Comment: I think my ProjectController also controls the details of each project, since it has createProject() and deleteProject() inside it. But I tried making a task controller, and put it on the position you mentioned, it didn't work. So I put it right below <div ng-controller="ProjectController as project">, and it worked. Thank you so much man, you save my life.